# How to Stack circles using d3js with lable and values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to show data using stacked circles positioned equally spaced. New to d3.js. Searched for reference but no where to be found.

```
  d3.json("js/data/circlechart.json", function(error, jsonData) {

    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    var len = jsonData.length;
    var color = ["#80a1e6", "#5c7dc1" , "#4062a8", "#345499" , "#274582"];
    var objWidth = document.getElementById('circleChart').offsetWidth;

    var cwidth = objWidth ;
    var xc = cwidth / 2 ;
    var xy = (cwidth / 2 ) - 5 ;
    var r = xc + 20 ;
    xc = xc- 20;
    var ty = 25;

    var svgContainer = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").data(jsonData);
    svgContainer.attr("width", cwidth).attr("height", cwidth);

    for(var i =0;i<jsonData.length;i++){

        var r = r - 30;
        var circle = svgContainer.append("g");
        circle.append("circle").attr("cx", xc).attr("cy", xy).attr("r", r).attr("fill", color[i]);
        circle.append('text').attr('x', xc)
        .attr('y', ty).text(jsonData[i].name)
        .attr("fill","#fff")
        .attr("style","transform: translateX(-20px)")
        .attr("class","labelName");
        ty+=31;

    }


  });
```

and my json file data is

```
[ { "name":"Category 1", "count":"20" }, 
  { "name":"Category 2", "count":"40" },
  { "name":"Category 3", "count":"52" } ]
```

I'm trying to make as below

[image: Stacked Circles d3js]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your `jsonData` to `data()` function like

```
var circleContainer = svgSelection.selectAll("g")
  .data(jsonData)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
```

and then operate with this container:

```
circleContainer.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 100)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('r', function(d) {return d.count+'px'})
  .style('fill', 'none').style('stroke', 'black');
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/wv83mxpt/) for you

Comment: Thanks.. and how can polylines indicating lines can be added? I mean like in image.. not all outside of circles

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/wv83mxpt/2/ update for you. 
`Math.sqrt(2) * (r + r * i) / 2` is position of nearest point to right-bottom (formula `cos(π/4) = x/R`)